# Объединить синонимичные метки {"auth", "authentication", "аутентификация"}

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

В русском варианте написания используются две раздельные метки:

- [авторизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) - 502 вопроса;
- [authorization](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization) - 22 вопроса;
- [аутентификация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) - 104 вопроса;
- [authentication](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication) - 86 вопросов.

Также используется метка, объединяющая оба термина:

- [auth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auth) - 251 вопрос.

---

## Предложенное мной решение

Cинонимизировать пары {[авторизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f), [authorization](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization)} и {[аутентификация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f), [authentication](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication)}.

[auth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auth) следует либо отнести к одной из этих пар, либо пометить как запрещённую
(сам я отнёс бы её к [аутентификация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f), для симметрии с [en.so](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/authentication/synonyms)).

Comment: А это, между прочим, **разные вещи** (и их часто путают). На en.SO `auth` синоним для `authentication`, да и используется auth обычно именно в этом значении.

Comment: @D-side ни в коем случае не ставлю под сомнение. Речь о том, что пока [tag:auth] остаётся отдельной меткой без описания, она будет использоваться в обоих смыслах, как, собственно, сейчас и происходит.

Comment: Тогда, возможно, я не вполне понял, что вы считаете проблемой. Уточните вопрос?

Comment: @D-side именно неопределённость метки [tag:auth] я и считаю проблемой. К чему её ни отнести — вопрос будет погребён под отрицательной кармой. Поэтому я предложил синонимизировать русские варианты с полными английскими написаниями. Судьбу же самой метки [tag:auth] безропотно предаю в руки Экспертов.

Comment: Просто в вопросе вы описали текущую ситуацию, но не описали собственно суть проблемы, для которой можно предлагать решения. Она на поверхности, но всё-таки стоит указать её явно. Заодно и я минус снять смогу после правки :)

Comment: Предложенное мной решение в заголовке: синонимизировать {“авторизация”, “authorization”}. Логично было бы в таком случае синонимизировать и {“аутентификация", “authentication”}, а [tag:auth] либо отнести к одной из этих пар, либо пометить как запрещённую.

Answer (score 8):

На всякий случай предупрежу:

### Аутентификация и авторизация это разные вещи.

**Аутентификация** это проверка подлинности.

**Авторизация** это проверка доступа.

Но их часто путают, называя **авторизацией** на самом деле **аутентификацию**. На первых страницах вопросов по метке [auth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auth) совпадений близко к 100% (в некоторые не вникал).

Посему, предлагаю синонимы:

- [авторизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f):

  - [authorization](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization)
- [аутентификация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

  - [authentication](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication)
  - [auth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auth)

Comment: Близко к 100% на первой странице - этого мало для переноса `auth` → `аутентификация`. Нужно смотреть **каждый** вопрос отдельно.

Comment: @alexolut это требует подготовительной работы по выявлению вопросов, которые используют термин **авторизация** правильно и добавлению в них соответствующей метки. "Первые страницы" (половина вопросов по метке) показывают, что если они и существуют, то их очень мало.